# How to access on file system in WCF Service

Tags: iis, iis-6, wcf, wcf-security

Hi Experts
I Have a WCF Service that Host it on IIS.I want to write something in a text file using my service but I get an exception :"Access denied on (file path)..."

how I can get access to file system?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the account the IIS is running under write access to the directory or file you're trying to write to.  Note that this can be a security risk (that's why IIS doesn't have permissions to do this by default).